# ios7 - how to transition back to self

Tags: ios7

as per the following storyboard, I have a RootViewController (embedded in a TabBarController), which manage many ViewControllers with a vertical menu.

When this RootViewController did load, I check for client authentication, and if not yet authenticated, I switch to a ConnectViewController for remote authentication

```
@implementation WDURootViewController
....
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     if (!self.client.isAuthorized) {
         WDUConnectViewController *cvc = self.connectVC;
         [self addChildViewController:cvc];
         [self.view addSubview:cvc.view];
         [cvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
      }
}
```

when authentication is successful, I want to come back to the RootViewController...
so in my ConnectViewController, I call back  a `didConnect()` method to notify the RootViewController

```
@implementation WDUConnectViewController
....
- (IBAction)sendGrantRequest
{
....
 [self.client authorizeUser:login password:pwd
       onSuccess:^() {
           [self.workinOnIt stopAnimating];
           [self.connectButton setEnabled:YES];
           [(WDURootViewController *)self.parentViewController didConnect];
        }
```

and in the RootViewController, `didConnect()` method I try to switch the views, in transition from the ConnectViewController to the RootViewController

```
@implementation WDURootViewController
....
- (void)didConnect
{
    [self transitionFrom:self.connectVC To:self];
}
....
        - (void)transitionFrom:(UIViewController *)oldC To:(UIViewController *)newC
    {
        [oldC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:newC];
        [self transitionFromViewController: oldC toViewController: newC
                              duration: 0.25 options:0
                            animations: nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [oldC removeFromParentViewController];
                                [newC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            }];
    }

    - (WDUConnectViewController *)connectVC {
        if (_connectVC == nil) {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
            _connectVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WDUConnectViewController"];
            _connectVC.client = self.client;
        }
        return _connectVC;
    }
```

but the transition method is looping... I guess it's not the way to go , what's the simplest way?

Answer (score 0):

I got it , just updating the didConnect() method in the RootViewController

```
- (void)didConnect
{
    [self.connectVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.connectVC.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.connectVC removeFromParentViewController];
    [self awakeFromNib];
}
```